# Where is the counter?

Tags: assembly, x86, counter, masm

For my assignment on assembly, I was supposed to divide the counter. All I need help with is trying to point it out on here so I can go ahead and do that.

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_max PROC; named _max because C automatically prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate

push ebp
mov ebp, esp; stack pointer to ebp

mov ebx, [ebp + 8]; address of first array element
mov ecx, [ebp + 12]
mov ebp, 0
mov edx, 0
mov eax, [ebx]

loopMe:
cmp ebp, ecx
je allDone

cmp eax, [ebx + edx]
jg continue

mov eax, [ebx + edx]

continue:
add edx, 4
add ebp, 1
jmp loopMe

allDone :

pop ebp
ret
_max ENDP

END
```

Comment: You're loading the length into ECX.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "divide the counter".  Please explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov ebx, [ebp + 8]; address of first array element
> mov ecx, [ebp + 12]
> ```

If the second argument contains the *number of array elements*, then the code is correct and does not require changes other than **optimizations** of course!

---

But if the second argument contains the *total length of the array*, so eg. 28 for an array that has 7 dword elements, you would need to divide ECX by 4 in order to get a correctly functioning code. No need to use the `div` instruction on this, just shift to the right twice:

```
  mov ebx, [ebp + 8]  ; address of first array element
  mov ecx, [ebp + 12] ; total length of the array
  shr ecx, 2          ; DIVIDE THE COUNTER
  mov ebp, 0
  mov edx, 0
  mov eax, [ebx]
loopMe:
  cmp ebp, ecx
  je  allDone
  cmp eax, [ebx + edx]
  jg  continue
  mov eax, [ebx + edx]
continue:
  add edx, 4
  add ebp, 1
  jmp loopMe
allDone :
```

"divide the counter" is not your only option. Instead you can use the offset in EDX for a stop criterion:

```
  mov ebx, [ebp + 8]  ; address of first array element
  mov ecx, [ebp + 12] ; total length of the array
  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, [ebx]
loopMe:
  cmp edx, ecx
  je  allDone
  cmp eax, [ebx + edx]
  jg  continue
  mov eax, [ebx + edx]
continue:
  add edx, 4
  jmp loopMe
allDone :
```